# modrewrite question

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

i'm having a geo database like the following

```
id contintent
------------
1  europe
2  usa 

id country
-----------
21 germany
22 france

id  city
-----------
50 paris
51 berlin
```

let's say i'm having this url:
/show.php?contintentID=1&countryID=21&cityID=51

how can i translate it using modrewrite to a proper like:
/europe/germany/berlin/index.html

i think it's beyond usual modrewrite .. 
any ideas? please help - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why would it be beyond usual modrewrite? If you make sure there's a proper field in the database that has no special characters (I always call this field pre_field_seo, for news title this would be: new_title_seo) where I put the title without spaces, special characters etc. so SEO ready.

The demo data you provider is perfect, but make sure you don't have München for example, the right seo name would be munchen or muenchen in that case, whatever fits you best.

There's only one rewriterul needed:

```
RewriteRule /([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/index.html show.php?continentName=$1&countryName=$2&cityName=$3 [L]
```

Ofcourse this also means that show.php must be converted in order to find the names in your database instead of the IDs. The IDs however can be added and used with the following setup:

```
/1-europe/21-germany/51-berlin/index.html
```

In that case you would need this rewriterule:

```
RewriteRule /([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)/index.html show.php?continentID=$1&countryID=$3&cityID=$5
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. mod_rewrite cannot do this as it cannot access the database.

So instead you just need to write show.php so that it looks up the relative id numbers in the database and then constructs the new URL using the `$continent/$country/$city/index.html` and redirects to it using http_redirect.

Comment: this makes no sence, since he already has show.php, mod_rewrite is perfectly able to do so. Also your comments lacks information, without any knowledge on mod_rewrite (and you telling him mod_rewrite cannot do this), you kind of leave the guy in the dark here. Sorry 'bout the -1 I'm about to give.

Comment: Sorry @PENDO, I must have misunderstood the question. I thought @fuxi wanted to look up the database to map the query string of ID numbers to a pathname of corresponding names.

Comment: hehe, no worries! Those things happen! I removed the -1! (Sorry, can't remove unless you change your answer, if you will and reply back here I'll remove the -1)